# Admob Banner ad displaying at intervals

Tags: android, admob, banner-ads

i am using admob in my android application but the banner ad is shown at intervals.
Specifically , every x minutes it shown and then return back to be invisible.
i believe that this issue in my admob account configurations but i cannot figure it out.